# PHP using mysql_select_db: receiving "is not a valid MySQL-Link resource" error

Tags: php

Here is the skinny - I can connect to my database just fine but when I try to access my table inside the database I keep getting thrown this error code:

```
Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /var/www/clients/client11/web31/web/update.php on line 11
```

Here is my update.php code

```
<?php
$db_name = "X";
$db_pass = "X";
$db_user = "X";
$db_host = "localhost";

$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) || die(mysql_error());


$select = mysql_select_db('gold_market',$con) || die(mysql_error()); 

?>
```

Help. Please.

Comment: odd. but try: var_dump($con);

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the connection is not actually being made. You should check the result of mysql_connect(). It might be easier to use a bit more verbose code.
The PHP manual has a good example:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

```
<?php
$db_name = "X";
$db_pass = "X";
$db_user = "X";
$db_host = "localhost";

$con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
// var_dump($con); // you can uncomment this for debugging.
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($con);
```

A side note:
mysql_select_db is like "USE dbname". It doesn't "access the table inside the database".

Comment: Thanks for your input. The connection to the database is just fine and I was using a more verbose code before I posted. I did, however, implement the more verbose code and now am receiving this error: Connected successfully Access denied for user 'c11tgm'@'localhost' to database 'gold_market' ...As far as I'm concerned I have the correct privledges - I am even logged into phpmyadmin as that exact user..

Comment: @nanewk: Sometimes the host part of the user is overlooked. Make sure that c11tgm's host is localhost. Another reason could be that your DB is on another host. Is it the same machine?

Comment: I can connect to phpMyAdmin and run queries with the same login info.

Comment: @nanewk: Just because you can connect, doesn't mean it is the same host. Are you 100% sure that your http server and your mysql server are on the same machine or accessible via the same ip address/domain name?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   <?php
    $db_name = "X";
    $db_pass = "X";
    $db_user = "X";
    $db_host = "localhost";

    $con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
    if (!$con) { 
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
           }     
    $select = mysql_select_db('gold_market',$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

    ?>
```

Comment: @eva611 Still should try var_dump($con)

Comment: yes. as everyone suggested, should absolutely check the value. Simply suggested another way to pinpoint the error i guess.

Comment: I get this after uncommenting: resource(2) of type (mysql link) Connected successfullyAccess denied for user 'c11tgm'@'localhost' to database 'gold_market'

Comment: Access denied for user 'c11tgm'@'localhost' to database 'gold_market'

Comment: I am assuming the host is localhost since I can connect to the database without any issues what so ever. My credentials are fine. I am logged into phpMyAdmin and can run queries inside phpMyAdmin with the same user/login.

Answer (score 0):

I use `or die()` not `|| die()`
I don't know if it makes a difference but its worth a shot.

Comment: i know, just didn't know whether using "or" or "||" made a difference.

Comment: I don't think so. Though all the examples I see use OR. Perhaps OR predates ||.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seemed to be the mysql_select_db syntax. Have you tried something like this:

```
$con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
if (!$con) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$select = mysql_select_db('gold_market', $con);
if (!$select) {
    die ('Table unavailable : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Table unavailable : Access denied for user 'c11tgm'@'localhost' to database 'gold_market'